# Tips for speeding up douple-loop integral

Tags: matlab

I currently have the following code:

```
function v3matrix1 = v3(l,eigendata,sphere)

l0=l;
v3matrix1=zeros(2*l0+1,2*l0+1);

for m0=-l0:1:l0
 for m0p=-l0:1:l0
    fun=@(theta,phi)conj(Ylm(l0,m0,theta,phi)).*(-gamma11(1,eigendata,sphere,theta,phi)).*partialTheta2(l0,m0p,theta,phi).*sin(theta);
    v3matrix1(m0+l+1,m0p+l+1)=integral2(fun,0,pi,0,2*pi);
  end
end

end
```

It takes ~21 mins to run. I have tried to follow similar advice to that given here ([Speeding up a double loop over integrals with changing parameter function values in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420949/speeding-up-a-double-loop-over-integrals-with-changing-parameter-function-values)) by getting rid of the for loops using "arrayfun" and "meshgrid" but that didn't speed it up. I was wondering if anyone has any other tips or suggestions that might speed this code up?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It looks to me like calculating each integral will take quite some time, so there's not much you can do. I'm not surprised `arrayfun` didn't help, it is basically a loop in disguise, and even if the looping was faster, I'd imagine the bulk of the time would be spend in `integral2`. Try using the profiler to see how much time is taken up by `integral2`, if it's a large amount, there wont be much you can do without some mathematical insight that might let you simplify the integration.

Comment: It is possible to vectorize integrals with the `integral` function. `fun = @(x) [x.^2;2*x.^2]; integral(fun,0,1,'ArrayValued',true);`. However, I am not sure if that would work. You can always try though. This option should be available for `integral2` as well.

Comment: Have you tried a `parfor` loop? I have just a standard install of Matlab and it included the parallel toolbox.

Comment: Try to use [trapezoidal integration](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50505-double-trapezoidal-integral). It is much much faster than `integral2`.